# random given me 2 string not one

Tags: javascript, random

in quiz game this code give me 2 string not one from the list? i don't know why? i want one string from the list (alpha):

```
else if(qanswer.toLowerCase() == 'joker') {
        var alpha = [nia++,nca++];
        var beta = Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length);
        /*var gama = alpha[beta]*/
        var gama = alpha.splice(beta, 2);
        gama;       // lucky answer
        var seeansw = '<strike>'+ qanswer +'</strike><h4 id="iansw">Joker:</h4><div id="canswer">'+ canswer +'</div>';
      }
```

question 2 :
this code give me the precent it's work but give me numbers with 9 digits like 66.66666666666 , i want only one digit after comma.

```
perc = (nca / nqansw) *100;
```

Comment: You second parameter in your `splice` call is 2, which will return 2 elements. Perhaps you meant 1? For the second question, you can use `.toFixed(1)` to have it truncated to 1 decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 :
Try to make your code correspond to this snippet code

```js
        var alpha = [12,13,14,15];
        console.log('alpha: '+ alpha);
        var beta = Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length);
        console.log('beta: '+ beta);
        var gama = alpha.splice(beta, 1);
        console.log('gama: '+ gama);
```

Question 2 :

```
perc = (nca / nqansw) *100; 
perc = Round(perc ,1) // or perc.toFixed(1);
```

Comment: thank you the 2nd answer help me, but the 1st not work with me.

Comment: No sir, maybe my code is wrong, i want one result from alpha list every time, for gama only. And last line most like the orginal code (gama;) not (console.log(gama).

Comment: i made console.log to allow you to see it! but you can use it in your code but not like what you did : you cannot write line like this : gama;